# How to count # of events sent to event hub via Moq for Unit Testing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, azure-eventhub

I am writing **Unit Test** using **MOCK (Moq)** for my **Azure Event Hub**. The Unit Test is simple. When I send 1 message to my Event Hub, I need to make sure it does receive 1 message. This is what I am doing...

```
Mock<IEventHub> eventHubMock;

eventHubMock
    .Setup( client => client.SendBatchAsync( It.IsAny<IEnumerable<EventData>>() ) )
    .Returns( Task.CompletedTask );

// Some processing which sends 1 message to Event Hub.

// Now to verify that my mock did receive 1 message.

eventHubMock.Verify(
    client => client.SendBatchAsync(
    It.IsAny<IEnumerable<EventData>>() ) );
```

**QUESTIONS**

1. The above will just validate it received some EventData. How do I verify that it received 1 EventData ?
2. What other validation can I perform using Mock?
3. My code deals with 2 event Hubs. How do I make sure the message is sent to correct event hub ?

Comment: To verify that you pass only 1 `EventData` you can setup it like this: `It.Is<IEnumerable<EventData>>(e => e.ToList().Count == 1)`.The rule is 1 question per question(?). Also, your second question doesn't make sense...

Comment: The question in its current state is incomplete and therefore unclear. Read [ask] and then [edit] the question to provide a [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: There is an extra parameter you can give to Verify to say how many times you expect it to be called. Try `eventHubMock.Verify(
    client => client.SendBatch( your parameters here ), Times.Once);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `It.Is<T>(Expression)` method to do verifications of parameters:

```cs
eventHubMock.Verify(
    client => client.SendBatch(
        It.Is<IEnumerable<EventData>>(es => es.Count() == 0 && IsValid(es.First()))));
```

where `IsValid(EventData eventData)` is some helper method to check all that you want about the event.

Which Event Hub the event goes to is defined when you create the sender, not when you use it. So the check should be related to something that happens inside `Some processing which sends 1 message to Event Hub` block, hard to give any details right now.